# Array.reject!(&:empty?) removes non-blank object

Tags: ruby, arrays

I can't figure out why, but when using `reject!(&:empty?)`, non-empty objects are removed.

Example:

```
["example"].reject!(&:empty?)
```

Returns `nil`. However,

```
["example", ""].reject!(&:empty?)
```

Returns `["example"]`, like it should.

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject-21):

> Equivalent to `#delete_if`, deleting elements from self for which the block evaluates to true, **but returns nil if no changes were made**.

If you want to use the result of the array (and less interested in *changing* the array - use [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject) instead:

```
["example"].reject(&:empty?)
# => ["example"]
["example", ""].reject(&:empty?)
# => ["example"]
```

Comment: Oh wow, I read right over that first sentence. Thanks for solving my stupidity.